# Access KVM Guest from LXC Container (lxcbr0 -> host -> virbr0)

Tags: iptables, routing, kvm-virtualization, subnet, lxc

I am trying to access a Windows Guest on KVM from a Linux Guest in an LXC container.
Specifically, I only need to be able to access one port (TCP 4949 / munin) from said LXC container.

LXC is set up to use the default lxcbr0 bridge (IP 10.0.3.1) and the LXC guest has a static IP assigned to it (10.0.3.2).

KVM is set up to use the default virbr0 bridge (IP 192.168.122.1) and the KVM guest has a static IP assigned to it (192.168.122.10).

Which route / iptables entry do I need to add in order to be able to access 192.168.122.10:4949 from 10.0.3.2?

Comment: I can ping the LXC guest from the KVM guest but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that apparently when those two bridges are initialized sequentially, their respective iptables rules also get entered in the same sequence. This means that the reject rules for one bridge override the accept rules (for forwarding) of the other bridge.
I solved this by simply adding this to my /etc/network/interfaces configuration:

up iptables -I FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
  down iptables -D FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Another method would be the reordering of the iptables rules once they are written, in order to put the reject rules to the end of the block. But in my oppinion, this would add overhead and would be more of a dirty workaround than the solution suggested above (one would have to do an "iptables-save" with a dump file, then reorder it and then call "iptables-restore" (et al) on bootup or interface up).